# Flag(mark) icons in windows

Tags: windows-7

Is it possible to flag(mark) icons in windows 7?
as you see below the C drive is flagged with windows flag. I want to flag folders for special purposes, (e.g. to show that I've seen this folder before, or there is some special things in this folder ,...)

[image]

in Linux we can flag(named embles) a folder icon. Is there anyway to do so in windows?
[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't think there's an standard way to do so, unless you install some 3rd party software or tweak some dll's.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you actually want to do, what arielnmz said is correct. There might be 3rd-Party Software doing what you need.

If you know how to code, there is the option to use [Icon Overlay Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127442%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This is an API supplied by Windows. There are options to create Overlays, there are "Tutorials" for that, you can look them up [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/545781/NET-Shell-Extensions-Shell-Icon-Overlay-Handlers) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7484/How-to-overlay-an-icon-over-existing-shell-objects).

It looks interesting and I might try to do something like that, but I'm a bit short on time.